# setting session variables into drop down menu selected item

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, session-variables

I have a php drop down which populates from mysql

When a user selects a drop down item, i would like to store this selected value in a session variable

The reason for doing this is, that i need to call this session variable to dynamically update second drop down based the previous selection..

how can i do this?
Thanks,

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                                            {
                                            echo '<option value="' . $row2['subject_id'] . '">' . $row2['subjectname']. '</option>';
                                            }
                                            echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in PHP without calling another PHP file, e.g. by sending a form. The code to set a session variable is trivial:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['selectname'] = $_REQUEST['selectname'];

?>
```

Comment: i have made some changes to question for clarity

Comment: ok , just as you said,that cant work without sending the form first.can you suggest an alternative to dynamically update second drop down based on values selected in first drop down?

Comment: There are tons of solutions for that specific problem out there, e.g. something JQuery-derived (whereas you can reload the entries for the second dropdown box by an AJAX request). However, this is far outside the scope of this question, and should probably be put in another one.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous comment mentioned, to "dynamically" update a session variable you'd have to use javascript (jQuery is a good library to use). If you add a event handlers to the dropdown box: `onChange='updateVar();'` and then create a javascript function to update the value of the variable. One way this function could work is to use ajax to call a php page which updates the session variable.

A jQuery example:

```
 $("select[name='dropdownBox']").change(function() { //event handler
        newvalue = $(this).val(); //get selected value
        $.ajax({
                    type : 'GET',
                    url : 'ajax.php',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : {
                        p : 'updateVar',
                        v : newvalue
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                       //on success code
                    },
                    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       //on error code
                    }
                });
 } );
```

Then you just need a simple php script that grabs the $_GET variables and updates the $_SESSION variables required.

Hope this helps